# How to create file in JavaScript from text

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing JavaScript code to initiate a download of a file in the browser. I am able to get the bytes of the file in a string and I want to pass the string to a function that creates a file and initiates a download from it.

I have to avoid just storing the file on the server for someone to download through html like:

```
<a href="./some-file.pdf">file</a>
```

Here is the code I have so far which works just fine, but I need to modify the extension of the file to change it to  match the data, which is the part I havn't figured out.

```
function download(data, filename = "aserc", type = ".txt") {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
    {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    } else  {
        var a = document.createElement("a"), url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
        }, 0); 
    }
}
```

this will download a file but it will not be a .txt file.
How do I change the type of the file using this code?

Comment: can you please try this , https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/qm5AG/

Comment: @KrushnakantLadani thank you, I think that will work

Comment: blob type should be a MIME type, `text/plain` perhaps?, not a file extension ... filename should be `aserc.txt`

Comment: `a.download = filename + type` and add the required header

Comment: @JaromandaX Quick question. What if the file is a .msi file? what MIME type would I use?

Comment: it's a binary file - so `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @KeithBecker According to http://filext.com/file-extension/MSI, mime types `application/x-ole-storage, text/mspg-legacyinfo` should work

Comment: @TheChetan I have tried using that mime type and when I download the .msi file using my javascript it is corrupted. I am using XMLHttpRequest to get the data. not sure what's the problem. The file downloaded is about twice the size as the original.

Answer (score 1):

Add the file extension to the name of the file. Like this

```
a.download = filename + ".txt";
```

Looking at the docs the Blob object takes in 'plain/text' for the type attribute to specify text this may be something you should keep an eye on, change Blob declaration to

```
var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'plain/text'});
```