# How can I save a .txt file from the value of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, save

I want to be able to write some text in a textarea and click a button to have the browser download a .txt file with the text I wrote in my textarea.

I have no idea how to go about this. What should I try?
Is there any way I cam have it downloaded to me without using a database or a server?

Comment: get text from textarea frist.
and follow like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789444/how-to-create-file-in-javascript-from-text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get data from text area:

```
var textcontent = document.getElementById("textareaID").value;
```

To download as txt file:

```
var downloadableLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadableLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(textcontent));
downloadableLink.download = "myFile" + ".txt";
document.body.appendChild(downloadableLink);
downloadableLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadableLink);
```

Comment: I tried putting it in the <script>. It doesn't seem to work. I'm very new to coding, I may just be doing it wrong.

Comment: I tried it again....worked perfectly...thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems if you run this multiple times, then it tries to download the same file multiple times. I would have thought removeChild would eliminate this problem. Is there something else we are missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an input field with `<textarea>` inside it.

Example:
HTML

```
<h2>Create .txt file</h2>
<div>
   <label for="fname">File name (without .txt):</label>
   <br>
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
   <label for="fcontent">File Content:</label>
   <br>
   <textarea id="fcontent" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
   <br>
   <button id="create">Create File</button>
   <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download Here</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
    var textFile = null,
        makeTextFile = function(text) {
            var data = new Blob([text], {
                type: 'text/plain'
            });

            if (textFile !== null) {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
            }

            textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

            return textFile;
        };


    var create = document.getElementById('create');
    var fileContent = document.getElementById("fcontent");

    create.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const fileName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        document.getElementById("downloadlink").setAttribute("download", fileName);
        var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
        link.href = makeTextFile(fileContent.value);
        link.style.display = 'block';
    }, false);
})();
```

You can see the live demo [here](https://codepen.io/hisamafahri/pen/MWjKrJp).

NOTE: If you want to make an HTML file be the default instead of a .txt file, you can do that by changing the `type: 'text/plain'` in the JavaScript file into `type: 'text/html'`

Comment: How can I make this an HTML file be default instead of a .txt file. How do I save it as .html? @hisam

Comment: Hi, you can do that by changing the `type: 'text/plain'` in you JavaScript file into `type: 'text/html'`

Answer (score 0):

See the working example on [JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/techieboy8080/v3b4nmo1/)

Javascript/JQuery

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
     var data = $('#mytextarea').val();
     this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,"  + encodeURIComponent(data);
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<a id="mybutton" href="" download="output.txt">Export to .txt</a>
```